Issue with Opening Sentinel-1 Product in SNAP: GDAL Data Type Error
I am encountering an error when trying to open a Sentinel-1 product in SNAP (Sentinel Application Platform). The error message is as follows:

I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem or have any suggestions on additional steps I can take to troubleshoot and fix this error?

Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than only in a picture.
